# ashx page giving 404 on https, while working fine on http

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, https

Other pages (aspx) are working fine on both http/https, only ashx gives response 404 on https, I used firefox firebug to investigate it.

I have two same virtual directory on IIS, one is mapped for https where this ashx is not working.

I guess some kind of mapping is missing for https on server, not sure where this kind of mapping is stored?

Comment: How are we able to provide a solution if you discribe your problem as similar to the problem of someone else? You need to provide more details

Comment: Does other aspx page work on HTTPS? Have you configured an SSL certificate in your web server?

Comment: SSL is configured and working on web server. Rest of the website is working fine, this is only about ashx page. even the path is correct i have checked, even then server is giving 404.

Comment: whats version iis? is there any redirection in ahsx file?

Comment: IIS7 Windows 2008, not sure where redirection mapping exist?

Answer (score 1):

- check your iis configuration, Default web site->application->Handler mappings check if .ashx registered
- if handler is consumed in dll you should add handler mapping also to web.config file ( webserver section)

once i had some kind of issue. it wasn't about handler mappings. i declared error file in web.config but it didn't exist on file system so  error happens in ashx file and request is   redirect to error page but error page is not there so i got 404 error. maybe your problem could be something like this.

to understand problem truly add a simple handler file and request it via browser see if any problem occurs.

Comment: What changes needs to be done on Web.config, I have checked on server *.ashx is mapped with dll.